# ie7 and UTF8 problems in classic asp

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic, utf-8

I'm having problems with utf-8 coming up as squares in ie7.  It works fine in firefox, opera, camino and safari.

One of the many characters that I'm trying to use is ✱ - Which is `&#10033;`. IE7 has this problem with characters used in this notation or pulled from the database (All other browsers display the characters correctly).

My head contains the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

I'm also sending the following commands in my response:

```
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
```

I can't seem to get it to work and unfortunately my biggest userbase is using IE.

Any solutions?

Comment: Looks fine to me in IE7 on this page..

Comment: Strange, even on Stack overflow in IE7, that utf character comes up as a square

Comment: Tried it on 2 machines here, 7.0.5730.13, works fine on both of them.. comes up as a "star" type symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with your version of IE7 ;) If all other browsers work fine and IE7 not ...

BTW, the "star"-like character you mention in your question looks fine in IE7 on my machine...

Answer (score 0):

it's worth double checking what encoding IE7 is set to, have you got it set to auto or is it set to use a different character set? Sometimes simply resetting it to auto can fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to save the file in UTF-8 format? This could also make a difference...